# Asp.net core 3.1 & Angular : Little problem for request

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, httprequest

I am currently developing a small e-commerce site with aspnet core 3.1 and Angular 9 and I have an error during an order validation.

when I validate an order, I receive a type 500 error, I cannot understand where the problem comes from, the pre-order is supposed to appear in the administration area after validation, but it does not work for the moment so if anyone can help me that would be really good because i'm really stuck

[error network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiGQO.png)

order model (clientapp) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cart } from './cart.model';
import { Repository } from './repository';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class Order {

  constructor(
    private repo: Repository,
    public cart: Cart,
    private router: Router
    ) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart))
    .subscribe(event => {
        if (router.url.startsWith('/checkout')
            && this.name != null && this.address != null) {
            repo.storeSessionData('checkout', {
                name: this.name,
                address: this.address,
                cardNumber: this.payment.cardNumber,
                cardExpiry: this.payment.cardExpiry,
                cardSecurityCode: this.payment.cardSecurityCode
            });
        }
    });
    repo.getSessionData('checkout').subscribe(data => {
        if (data != null) {
            this.name = data.name;
            this.address = data.address;
            this.payment.cardNumber = data.cardNumber;
            this.payment.cardExpiry = data.cardExpiry;
            this.payment.cardSecurityCode = data.cardSecurityCode;
        }
    });
 }

  orderId: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  // tslint:disable: no-use-before-declare
  payment: Payment = new Payment();
  // tslint:disable: no-inferrable-types
  submitted: boolean = false;
  shipped: boolean = false;
  orderConfirmation: OrderConfirmation;


  get clothes(): CartLine[] {
    return this.cart.selections
      .map(p => new CartLine(p.clotheId, p.quantity));
  }

  clear() {
    this.name = null;
    this.address = null;
    this.payment = new Payment();
    this.cart.clear();
    this.submitted = false;
  }

  submit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.repo.createOrder(this);
  }
}

export class Payment {
  cardNumber: string;
  cardExpiry: string;
  cardSecurityCode: string;
}

export class CartLine {
  constructor(private clotheId: number,
    private quantity: number) {}
}

export class OrderConfirmation {
  constructor(public orderId: number,
    public authCode: string,
    public amount: number) {}
}
```

the service :

```
  getOrders() {
    this.http.get<Order[]>(ordersUrl)
      .subscribe(data => this.orders = data);
  }
  createOrder(order: Order) {
    this.http.post<any>(ordersUrl, {
      name: order.name,
      address: order.address,
      payment: order.payment,
      clothes: order.clothes
    }).subscribe(data => {
      order.orderConfirmation = data;
      order.cart.clear();
      order.clear();
    });
  }
  shipOrder(order: Order) {
    this.http.post(ordersUrl + '/' + order.orderId, null)
      .subscribe(r => this.getOrders());
  }
```

order.component.html :

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <table *ngIf="orders?.length > 0; else nodata" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Clothes</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let o of orders">
        <td>{{o.name}}</td>
        <td>{{o.address}}</td>
        <td>{{o.clothes.length}}</td>
        <td>{{o.payment.total | currency:'USD'}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="!o.shipped; else shipped">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="markShipped(o)">
                Ship
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <ng-template #shipped>
    <td>Shipped</td>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #nodata>
    <h3 class="text-center">There are no orders</h3>
  </ng-template>

</div>
```

order.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Repository } from 'src/app/models/repository';
import { Order } from 'src/app/models/order.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-admin',
  templateUrl: './order-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-admin.component.css']
})
export class OrderAdminComponent {

  constructor(private repo: Repository) { }

    get orders(): Order[] {
        return this.repo.orders;
    }
    markShipped(order: Order) {
        this.repo.shipOrder(order);
    }

}
```

my controller :

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Eshop.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Eshop.Controllers
{
     [Route("/api/orders")]
    public class OrderValuesController : Controller
    {
        private DataContext context;
        public OrderValuesController(DataContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
        {
            return context.Orders
            .Include(o => o.Clothes).Include(o => o.Payment);
        }
        [HttpPost("{id}")]
        public void MarkShipped(long id)
        {
            Order order = context.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order != null)
            {
                order.Shipped = true;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateOrder([FromBody] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                order.OrderId = 0;
                order.Shipped = false;
                order.Payment.Total = GetPrice(order.Clothes);
                ProcessPayment(order.Payment);
                if (order.Payment.AuthCode != null)
                {
                    context.Add(order);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        orderId = order.OrderId,
                        authCode = order.Payment.AuthCode,
                        amount = order.Payment.Total
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Payment rejected");
                }
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        private decimal GetPrice(IEnumerable<CartLine> lines)
        {
            IEnumerable<long> ids = lines.Select(l => l.ClotheId);
            return context.Clothes
            .Where(m => ids.Contains(m.ClotheId))
            .Select(m => lines
            .First(l => l.ClotheId == m.ClotheId).Quantity * m.Price)
            .Sum();
        }
        private void ProcessPayment(Payment payment)
        {
            // integrate your payment system here
            payment.AuthCode = "12345";
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the console say :

```
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)   
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)    
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:161:44)        
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:42:54)
    at processResource (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
          at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:313:20)
    at C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
    at processResource (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:292:3)


fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootswatch' in 'C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\ClientApp\src'

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value 
of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](T node, String callerName)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitParameters(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IParameterProvider nodes, String callerName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)   
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(IQueryable`1 source)
   at Eshop.Controllers.OrderValuesController.GetPrice(IEnumerable`1 lines) in C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\Controllers\OrderValuesController.cs:line 63
   at Eshop.Controllers.OrderValuesController.CreateOrder(Order order) in C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\Controllers\OrderValuesController.cs:line 40 
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The stack trace shows the error is coming `at Eshop.Controllers.OrderValuesController.GetPrice(IEnumerable\`1 lines) in C:\Users\Spartacus\Desktop\Core.net\ClotheShop\Controllers\OrderValuesController.cs:line 63`. I'm guessing it has something to do with the `lines.First(l => l.ClotheId == m.ClotheId)` code. That's probably returning null for one of the `lines`.

Comment: Oh okay, I am looking at this but I do not see what could solve the problem. I get this message every time:

System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.